# Writing a static array of objects

Tags: javascript

I need help formatting this response. Below is a response that I'm getting from a server. I'd like to write out a static version of this but I'm struggling with the formatting of how to write it.

Response I want to write:

```
[
    category1: [{...},{...}], 
    category2: [{...},{...}], 
    category3: [{...},{...}]
]
```

My attempt:

```
const myArr = [
    "category1": [{...},{...}],
    "category2": [{...},{...}],
    "category3": [{...},{...}]
]
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong here? Thank you! Apologises for the n00b question.

Comment: There's some differences in arrays and objects, and I think that you need an object, not array. https://dev.to/zac_heisey/objects-vs-arrays-2g0e

Comment: Arrays don't have "named" elements. Maybe you want an object instead: `{category1: [...], ...}`.

Answer (score 3):

You've written something that's a cross between an array literal and an object literal. It needs to be one or the other.

An array literal, containing arrays of objects:

```
const myArr = [
    [{/*...*/},{/*...*/}],
    [{/*...*/},{/*...*/}],
    [{/*...*/},{/*...*/}]
];
```

You access the "category1" array via `myArr[0]`, "category2" via `myArr[1]`, etc.

An object literal, containing arrays of objects as the values of properties:

```
const myObj = {
    category1: [{/*...*/},{/*...*/}],
    category2: [{/*...*/},{/*...*/}],
    category3: [{/*...*/},{/*...*/}]
};
```

You access the "category1" array via `myObj.category1`, "category2" via `myObj.category2`, etc.

Although it's *possible* to give arrays arbitrary named properties (because arrays are objects), you can't do so in an array literal (you have to create the array first, then add the properties), and you usually don't want to do it anyway. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can only use keys in an object not in an array. Try like this:

```js
const myArr = {
    "category1": [{...},{...}],
    "category2": [{...},{...}],
    "category3": [{...},{...}]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong from that request because there is no result format like that. Make sure you have the correct response.

Object version:

```
const myArr = {
    "category1": [{...},{...}],
    "category2": [{...},{...}],
    "category3": [{...},{...}]
};
console.log(Object.keys(myArr).map((key) => myArr[key]));
```